# Hyperledger Fabric (How many peers for network with many organizations)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, ibm-blockchain

Recently, I've been diving into the Hyperledger Fabric documentations on network strucutre, design concepts, etc. One question that I haven't been able to find a clear answer to is this:

When creating a network with many organization (30+), do you assign each organization a peer, or can multiple organization be hosted on a single or small collection of peers? What is best practice for creating networks with many organizations (30+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one peer per organization (preferably more). It makes no sense sharing a peer between organizations. Would your company share its resources (and even its keys) with its partners (or even competitors)?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, thinking out loud, it might make a difference depending on how the organizations are going to interact in the network.  As in, are all 30 organizations going to transact or is it say Org 1 owns the peer, Org 2, 3, 4, 5 are clients of Org 1, in which case they may just need an app that connects to to the network via Org 1?

Doesn't answer the question directly, but food for thought.

Comment: I have quite a same problem here. I have an Org who host the fabric n/w and other clients (consume) the n/w. However, the clients number is unknown, it can 30, 50,100 ..N. One more important thing is each client should maintain a private channel, in this case, i should create each client a new organization right? or is there any other way of limiting the orgs by handling with more number of peers?